# Messages between Virtual Box and an Amazon Instance - Python socket.error: Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets, port

I am trying to send messages between Amazon Deep Learning AMI instance, running somewhere, and an Ubuntu Virtual Box Machine running in my LAN.

I have opened port 2019 for both TCP and UDP in my LAN. I have also enabled DMZ for my Ubuntu Virtual Machine IP, which I got running `ifconfig`. The virtual box machine is using "Bridge networking".

I have disabled my firewalls and created rules for allowing connections in port 2019.

However... When I run in my Ubuntu Virtual Box Machine (in my LAN):

```
Servidor = sk.socket()
Servidor.bind(('localhost', 2019))
print("Esperando al cliente...")
Servidor.listen(1)
a, b = Servidor.accept()
print("Cliente aceptado. Arrancando el Juego")
```

And this, in my Amazon Deep Learning Instance:

```
Cliente = sk.socket()
Cliente.connect(("MY_LAN_PUBLIC_IP", 2019))
print("Conectado al cliente")
```

I get:

```
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I have checked if my port is opened using this website http://canyouseeme.org/ and It says that the port is closed, but I don't understand why...

[CanYouSeeMe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ4Gk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this on your Ubuntu machine on a separate terminal

`ssh -L <local-port>:<remote-IP>:<Remote-Port> -N <remote-user>@<remote-IP>`

This will start forwarding your =2019 traffic (local traffic) to the AMI Instance which is a remote machine in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done what you told me and I get no response: https://imgur.com/35URyiz What may be wrong?

Comment: Check if that port is not already used by another program using 'netstat -tulpn | grep <your-port>' and if it is used by another program try changing the local port (other than 2019)